# How to compare a string-array to a real-array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I take a output array-string from a php-file with help from ajax. 
The string is like: `{latLng: [53.0854, 8.7463]},`. 
Now I will take this coordinates and reflect it with help from this jQuery plugin http://jvectormap.com/. 
These are the coordinates from Bremen, but it shows me a point at Africa. 
I think the problem is being its a string. 
Knows anyone how I can change the string to a real integer array?

My js-function:

```
          function map(marker) {
    $('#world-map-markers').vectorMap({
      map: 'world_mill_en',
      scaleColors: ['#C8EEFF', '#0071A4'],
      normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
      hoverOpacity: 0.7,
      regionsSelectable: false,
      hoverColor: false,
      markerStyle: {
        initial: {
          fill: '#e74c3c',
          stroke: '#e74c3c'
        }
      },
      backgroundColor: '#383f47',
      markers: marker
    });
  }

  function map_refresh() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "traffic_query.php",
        data: "traffic",
        success: function(traffic){
            var array = [traffic];
            map(array);
        }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Apologies for being thick but I don't think your example is complete. Where do you use your `LatLng` for example?

Comment: maybe you just need to switch the co-ords around? I tried them both ways in google maps and I get Bremen one way and the coast of Somalia the other

Comment: @andrew: no i have tested it in javascript without a string-request.   kkuilla: i have added the full code.

Answer (score 0):

They are not a string. They are encoded as a numeric variable.

```
var json = {latLng: [53.0854, 8.7463]};
var correctCoordArray = getCorrectCoordsArray(json); 

function getCorrectCoordsArray(coords) {
  var coordsArray = [];
  //switchCoords as pointed out
  coordsArray.push(coords.latLng[1]);
  coordsArray.push(coords.latLng[0]);
  return coordsArray;
}
```

Comment: Meistens sind es aber mehrere Koordinaten die ich zurückbekomme und halt über ein komma getrennt sind.

Comment: Then include a server response that includes  representative content. I am still running crystal ball 1.0, which is not that advanced. ;o)